# Jira Integration for Jenkins new create issue

Tags: jenkins, jira

firstly i have tried to new create issue in Jira from Jenkins. But it is not successful. i spent to 3 days for how i can solve this issue.

when i completed integration between jira and jenkins site. There is one

link  http://jirasite.com/rest/api/2 .... in in Jira Integration for Jenkins monitor (under the manage jenkins)

But i deleted it. now i couldn't create again link in jenkins. There is below warning.

Jira Integration for Jenkins
Jira Sites cannot be added directly here in Jenkins, this Jenkins instance needs to be configure in Jira.
No Jira Sites available.

I got this below error message after jenkins job build fail for jira create

```html
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraSession.createIssue(JiraSession.java:412)
 at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraCreateIssueNotifier.createJiraIssue(JiraCreateIssueNotifier.java:202)
 at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraCreateIssueNotifier.currentBuildResultFailure(JiraCreateIssueNotifier.java:357)
 at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraCreateIssueNotifier.perform(JiraCreateIssueNotifier.java:157)
 at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
 at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1840)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'JIRA: Create issue' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How I can solve this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Jira configuration by clicking on validate settings. some values like component, issue type is might be missing, i faced same issue and found the value of issue type and issue priority was reset. i hope this might help you.